# Highlight search terms on keyup jquery using jquery highlight plugin

Tags: jquery, highlight

Ok I am trying to bolden search terms from a search text box in my HTML page. I am using the jQuery highlight plugin here[jQuery highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) to try and achieve this. Am still not proficient in jQuery so pardon me if this sounds too dumb

The problem is that it only highlights the first character entered in the text box and the rest are ignored.

1. The highlight.js can be found [here](https://raw.github.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/master/jquery.highlight.js)
2. Here's my code

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Test page for Highlight Search Terms</title>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="highlight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
               $('.x').highlight($(this).val());

       });    
   });
   </script>
   <style type="text/css">
     .highlight {
       font-weight: bold;
     }
   </style>
   <body>
     <input type="text" id="search"></input>
      <p class="x">Highlight plugin searches through the text of given elements
       in this case to find the term (word 'highlight' in our example) to 
       highlight. When the term is found it's simply wrapped with </p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

I want it to match every search term from the text box in the paragraph and bolden it. What am I not doing right? Thanks

Comment: Try unhighlighting the paragraph before doing more highlighting.

Comment: Thanks worked perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever the highlighting something it is adding a span tag for the word you have search.
In your case you have to unhighlight the previous highlighted text to remove the span added by plugin.
You can try it like following.
Hope it will work

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
                $('.x').unhighlight();
                $('.x').highlight($(this).val());

        });    
    });
    </script>
```